# BSS138W MOSFET unexpectedly blowing

Tags: mosfet

So I have a piece of circuitry that contains the schematic below. Q10 on this schematic keeps blowing and I'm looking for help to figure out why. +VBATA can be anywhere from 7V to 18V, the output going off the right side of the screen just goes through a resistor into a micro controller to be read and the A2D_READ_BAT input shown goes to the same controller to turn on Q10.

Q10 (BSS138W) Characteristics:

Vdds: 50V 
Vdgr: 50V
Vgs: +-20V
Id: 200mA
Pd: 200mW
Vgs: 1.2V
Rds: 1.4Ohm

A2D_READ_BAT: 3.3V

Is there simply something I'm just not seeing?

[image: Q10 Circuitry]

Comment: what is the value of VBAT on the right side of the schematic?

Comment: It's just +VBATA that flows through Q12, it goes through a voltage divider and is fed into a micro controller to be read.

Comment: How is Q10 failing? "blowing" isn't too helpful. Is ESD damage possible? Also, how quickly is Q10 switching? Hz? kHz? MHz?

Comment: What is the voltage swing on A2D_READ_BAT?  The [datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds30206.pdf) says the Vgs(th) gate threshold voltage is max 1.5 volts with a note saying the test was performed with a short pulse to avoid self-heating.  What is the maximum time A2D_READ_BAT is high?

Comment: Blowing as in the component is visually blown, not just ESD. I will check the frequency in a second for you, I have to check. As for the A2D_READ_BAT swing it is 0-3.3V but it is for a very low pulse time just to grab a reading.

Comment: As for the frequency it is 1 Hz. So it's pretty darn slow

Comment: Check if actual hw is like the scheme. My impression is that either some other components failed and you don't know that, or you have a mistake in assembly, so the scheme doesn't reflect your hw.

Answer (score 2):

Q12 (M1 on my schematic) needs to be a P channel MOSFET with a VGS(max) of at least 20V, or you can add a resistor as shown to prevent the gate of q12 from breaking down.  Size R1 and R2 so that Q12 VGS is less than 12v when VBATA is 18.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f58OnE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Forgot to mention that Q12 is in fact a P-channel. (DMP2160UW)

Comment: It's fine, the scheme is clear

Comment: Sorry it is drawn as an N-channel, but it's still likely causing the problem.  See my edit.

Comment: It is a mosfet with 20 volt withstand voltage.

Comment: [DMP2160UW](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds31521.pdf) Maximum Ratings: Gate-Source Voltage Vgss ±12V

Comment: On the original design, VGS on Q12 can be 18 if Q10 is on.  The gate-source junction will zener making one or other of the FETs unhappy.

Comment: I must have had a brain fart while reading the datasheet, for some reason I swore that it said ±20V. I just ordered some ±20V replacements to try out to see if that resolves the issue.